# Using include to join related entity in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, join

I am developing an Asp.net mvc project. I am using EF code first approach to interact with code first approach. But there is one thing I seriously want to know and that is what I do not know about EF yet. What I want to do is I want to join related entities using include without using Join().

I have entities like this

```
public class Place{
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts;
}


public class Contact{
    public Place Place;
    public Area Area;
}

public class Area{
   public ICollection<Contact> Contacts; 
}
```

In above condition I am trying to retrieve places but all related entities are joined using Include.

This is what I am doing

```
context.Places.Include("Contacts").Include("Area");
```

It threw error.

[image]

But I know I can use join statement to retrieve all. But code will be a little complicated. So is it possible to join using Include in above condition? Is join the only option here?

Comment: What error dit it threw?

Comment: What about `context.Contacts.Include("Place").Include("Area");`?

Comment: I added the error in question @TomWuyts

Comment: It just throws the same error. @SlavaUtesinov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just not use *strongly typed version* of Include? You can retrieve *Contacts* and *Areas* simply:

```
context.Places.Include(m => m.Contacts.Select(c => c.Area));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do is this:

```
context.Places.Include("Contacts.Area");
```

When chaining includes, write them as one include as above.

In your original, it would look for the property `Area` in the object `Places`. But it cannot find it there.